# How should I ask about a contraction meaning?

Tags: contractions

Please help me to ask the sentence below properly.

*to what word the contraction **"d"** refers to in **"he'd"***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the "'d" (read *apostrophe-d*) in "he'd" short for?

Comment: Thank you very much Damkerng T. Is my sentence wrong? would please improve the sentence that I have suggested?

Comment: To keep it as close as your sentence as possible, I believe you can say "To what word does the contraction "'d" in "he'd" refer?" or "What word does the contraction "'d" in "he'd" refer to?". (And actually, I think your sentence works just fine.)

Comment: It can be difficult to read "'d", especially if your eyesight isn't so good.  On Stack Exchange, you can instead write `'d`, which is easier to read.

Comment: You might also consider the simplest form: "What is *he'd* a contraction of?" You don't have to call out the *'d* portion. The answer to that question would be "he had", not just "had", but... You still get the answer you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it you mean

> In the contraction ***he’d***, what word does the ***’d*** represent?

I put the written elements you refer to in italics rather than quotes because that is the convention here, and generally in linguistic studies. I also boldfaced these elements, partly to make them stand out and partly because the marks of punctuation in the face employed here are not very legible.

---

If you are asking that question (and not just how to ask it) ... it varies. It’s always an auxiliary, but which auxiliary is apparent only in context.

> I went to find Jim—I hoped he’d tell me where I could find the Blakely file—but he’d already gone.

The first *he’d* here is parsed *he would*. It is followed by a ‘plain’ form, here an unmarked infinitive, so the modal auxiliary is required.

The second is parsed *he had*. It it is followed by the past participle gone, which takes the auxiliaries *have* and *be*. *Be* has no *-d* forms, so it must be *had*.